# Can't install Cyanogenmod on Galaxy S3

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I can't seem to get Cyanogenmod installed onto my Galaxy S3. I've followed the steps on their [website](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_d2lte), and I've gotten the custom recovery installed just fine. But actually installing the Cyanogenmod Nightly isn't working, both for the sideload and push and install.

I am admittedly new to Cyanogenmod so I'm not sure what's going on with it, or if I'm getting a simple step wrong.

When I try installing from zip in the recovery nothing actually happens and nothing changes when I reboot the phone.

Then when I try to install it via push and install, I use the command:

```
adb push cm-11-20150426-NIGHTLY-d2lte.zip /sdcard/0/
```

It tells me:

```
3426 KB/s (227230178 bytes in 64.765s)
```

And again when I try booting the phone up nothing has changed.

I got something different when I took the /0/ out of the code
So I put in:

```
adb push cm-11-20150426-NIGHTLY-d2lte.zip /sdcard/
```

And I get:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon start successfully *
error: insufficient permissions for device
```

Thank you Firelord (I'm new here so I'm not sure if I'm able to include a quote of your answer)
I seemed to just be doing it out of order. 
Now that I've gotten it working I'm running into an issue with the install on the device.
When I try to install from the zip it tells me:

```
-- Installing /sdcard/0/cm-11-20150626-NIGHTLY-d2lte.zip
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Installing update...
Can't install this package on top of incompatible data. Please try another package or run a factory reset
E:Error in /sdcard/0/cm-11-20150426-NIGHTLY-d2lte.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted
```

I did a factory reset and got a new version of the zip before I edited the post and got the same error.

Comment: That `3426 KB/s` is the copying speed with which data is copied in that said SD card. `227230178 in 64.765s` is ~230MB data copied into the said location in 64.765 seconds. Seems like it's the size of your ROM.

Comment: `adb push cm-xxx.zip /sdcard/0` wouldn't install the ROM or any zip file but would just copy it from SOURCE to DESTINATION, as what `push` literally implies.

Comment: In order to install that file, it is mentioned in the link (step 7) to choose "install zip from sideload" so that you can do something like `adb sideload cm-xxx.zip`, or choose "push and install method" where you actually pushed the ROM but needed to do tap "Install zip" -> choose that ROM from SD card, and proceed for installation.

Comment: `error: insufficient permissions for device` -- I think you were running your Android OS when you entered that command.

Comment: Sorry! But I've lack of experience with Nightlies, so I'm unable to help you out anymore. Until somebody reaches you with help, I would suggest using Google search for the error. Also, you may see [referencing](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) to know site's rules for quoting the content. In addition, use @ followed by the name of the person to whom you are conveying your point. More info is [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was unsure if the @ would work here.
I'll give the Release channel a shot to see if that will work.